# Rails check a form is edited and let user confirm page redirection or close

Tags: ruby-on-rails

form posting is a very common operation on web site, and for better user experience, 
we need prevent user from mistaken close the window or click a wrong link, just like this page :)

So is there a standard way or gem to do it in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var edited = false;

$('#formId :input').change(function() {
    if(!edited) {
      edited = true;
    }
});

window.onbeforeunload = preventUser();

function preventUser() {
  if(edited) {
    alert("Are you sure?");
  }
}
```

Comment: The given answer didn't work entirely for me. I had to replace the `alert` with a `return` as per: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onbeforeunload

Comment: Also the `window.onbeforeunload` should be assigned a function reference, not a call. Eg `window.onbeforeunload = preventUser;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you wish to alert user when she enters data in a form and wants to leave the page. That's not related to rails, but to javascript.

You can do it like this:

`window.onbeforeunload = "Are you sure you want to leave?";`

You want to enable this option only when the data is entered in form so add this jQuery code

```
$('input').change(function() {
    if( $(this).val() != "" )
        window.onbeforeunload = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @harm and @shime answers, it worked for me this way:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return 'You have made changes'">
```